# Drawing a "Square" in Java

Tags: java, draw

I am trying to draw a "square" in Java using asterisks. I have a square class with an input parameter, I am trying to get the method to output lines of "*" so that there are as many "*" in a row and as many rows as the value stored in the class instance variable sideLength. So if the code has made a Square(3) then I want to output

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHvQ5.png)

via a method called drawSquare.

So far I have:

```
class Square {

    int sideLength;

    Square( int size ) {
        sideLength = size;
    }

    int getArea() {
        return sideLength * sideLength;
    }

    int getPerimeter() {
        return sideLength * 4;
    }

    void drawSquare() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square mySquare = new Square(4);
        int area = mySquare.getArea();
        int perimeter = mySquare.getPerimeter();
        System.out.println("Area is " + area + " and perimeter is " + perimeter);
        System.out.println("*" + )
        Square mySquare2 = new Square(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the purpose of this exercise to to help you learn about [for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is really easy, I'll give not the solution but just a few hints.

If you look at the square you made up, you'll see that, having a side-length of 3, it consists of 3 rows of 3 asterisks each.

To create one such row, you'd use a `for()` loop that goes from 1 to 3 and prints a `"*"` each time.

As you need 3 such rows, you'd enclose that first loop into another, that also goes from 1 to 3.

As final hint: `System.out.print("*")` prints an asterisk and does not start a new line. `System.out.println()` starts a new line.

Comment: So I would need one for loop that determines how many rows are needed by counting up to sideLength and using System.out.println(); to produce that number of rows. Then I would need another for loop that prints out a set number of asterisks and uses System.out.print("*") to print that number of asterisks on a row. 

That part now makes sense to me after doing a little bit of research on for loops, but I am confused as to how to get a void function to print out in the main system output.

Comment: Exactly. Loops are (besides `if()`) one of the most often used constructs of any programming language.

Comment: But how do I get a void method to output at the end of the program? I understand how to create a method in order to get the answer but cannot get it to output.

Comment: You probably found out by now - the void method does not return a value, but it can (via System.out.print()) output text to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use 2 nested for loops, to output a certain amount of asterisks in a line, then repeat that line the same amount of times.

```
for (int x = 0; x < sideLength; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < sideLength; y++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println(""); //Short for new line.
}
```

Comment: Prefer `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.println("")`

Comment: @dnault I didn't know that actually works. I only used this like a year ago last time.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This provided a good basis for me to start writing my own version of this code.

Answer (score -5):

nested for loops are an easy way to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< y; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < x; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: At least provide a wroking example

Comment: Teach to fish, don't give a fish.